# SWIFT - JSON error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, json, swift

How to correct this error: JSON error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format?

```swift
struct LanguageText: Decodable {
    let id_language: Int
    let language_text: String
}

func textLoad() {
    let switchcase = "loginWords"
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "switchcase=\(switchcase)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return // check for fundamental networking error
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
        } catch {
            print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

This is the JSON format:

```
[{"id_language":"15","language_text":"Female"},
 {"id_language":"16","language_text":"Male"},
 {"id_language":"17","language_text":"Other"},
 {"id_language":"1000","language_text":"Hello there!"}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Create a string from the `data` right before the `do` line and `print` it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to put id_language into a Int-Value, but in your JSON id_language is String.

Change id_language to String

```swift
struct LanguageText: Decodable {
    let id_language: String
    let language_text: String
}
```

Or you have to edit your JSON-File

```
[{"id_language":15,"language_text":"Female"},
 {"id_language":16,"language_text":"Male"},
 {"id_language":17,"language_text":"Other"},
 {"id_language":1000,"language_text":"Hello there!"}]
```

For parsing JSON I can recommend [this site](https://app.quicktype.io)

Comment: The type mismatch is another error. The struct is not involved (yet) in the code.

Comment: @vadian you are right, so my solution will prevent the next error :)

Answer (score 1):

In your model you could do something like this:

```swift
struct LanguageText: Decodable {
  let languageId: String
  let languageText: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case languageId = "id_language"
    case languageText = "language_text"
  }
}
```

In your `do catch` do the `data` parse:

```swift
do {
  let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([LanguageText].self, from: data)
} catch {
  print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get array from row data.

```
  let dataArray = getArrayFromJsonString(rowData: data)

  func getArrayFromJsonString(arrayString:String)-> [[String : Any]] {
    do {
        return try  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
        arrayString.data(using:
        String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, 
        options:
        JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [[String :
                Any]]
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of bad practices: 1) JSON collection objects are always `[String:Any]` not `[String:AnyObject]`. 2) `allowFragments` is pointless if the expected type is array or dictionary. 3) Print always a potential error in the `catch` scope. 4) A JSON string is always UTF8,  the `allowLossyConversion` parameter is irrelevant, you can even write `Data(arrayString.utf8)` which returns non-optional data.